# Do Banach-Alaoglu Theorems also hold for the closed ball of arbitrary radius $r>0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem, reflexive-space

I am aware of the three theorems, let $X$ be a normed space:

i) $\overline{B}_{1}(0)^{*}$ is weak-* compact

ii) if $X$ is seperable the $\overline{B}_{1}(0)^{*}$ is weak-* sequentially compact

iii) if $X$ is Banach: $X$ Reflexive $\iff \overline{B}_{1}(0)$ weakly compact

This begs the question whether the same holds for any $r \neq 1>0$, I assume it does by scaling the unit ball, but I am unsure. On a more general note:

Oftentimes in a proof we only look at the unit ball $B_{1}(0)$ around $0$, and then state that since it holds for $B_{1}(0)$ it holds for any ball centered at $x \in X$ and $ r >0$, that is it will hold for $B_{r}(x)$, because of translations and scaling. Can we always reduce a given problem to the unit ball? Or when does this not hold?

Comment: Yes, it works in this case. It's because translations and dilatations are continuous for the weak-* topology

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki And what about the strong and weak topology?

Comment: They are continuous in the strong topology as well (hence also in the weak and weak*)

Comment: You have the correct answer now, in two comments. But I think the best cure for your "I assume ... but I am unsure" situation is not to just accept the affirmations of experts but to write out complete, detailed proofs for yourself. That will help you develop a feeling for how such arguments work and why experts just take them for granted.